# Laravel ORM: How to filter records from a table in a M:M relation using a condition of the other table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have those two tables: `apps` and `categories`, they are in a M:M relationship, I have the `apps_categories` table in place and the `BelongsToMany()` relations in their models, they work fine.

Now, in a form I'm displaying all the records in apps, but I want to filter based on `category_id`, so I have a `$categories` array where I store the filters.

My problem is solved using the `DB` facade doing like:

```
$apps = DB::table('apps')
  ->join('apps_categories', 'apps.id', '=', 'app_id')
  ->whereIn('category_id', $categories)
  ->select('apps.*')
  ->get();
```

So, I was wondering if there's a better way, using only the ORM. Thing is I have another table with a M:M relationship to `apps`, and I'm supposing using the ORM would be a better way to handle both relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method for this:

```
$apps = App::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($categories) {
    $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categories);
})->get();
```

---

Same as the above but uses an arrow function:

```
$apps = App::whereHas('categories', fn ($query) => $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categories))->get()
```

---

The 1st argument for `whereHas` is the method name you have used for the relationship in your model (`categories`) and
1st argument for the `whereIn` is the table name and field (`categories.id`).

Comment: That's great, of course this must be in the documentarion ‍♂️. Thanks a lot!